# Native script google map custom marker icon

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I been trying to set a custom marker icon from a URL lately with no luck at all. I can set custom marker icon from an asset file but not a URL. Any help here would be appreciated. I'm using [dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) library. Please let me know if any code will be needed i can provide some.
this block of code is throwing a logged error " Cannot read property 'android' of undefined"

```
let image = new Image();
imageSource.fromUrl(iconUrl)
    .then(function(res){
        image.src = res;
        marker.icon = image;
        console.log("image loaded successfully");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error loading image " + error);

    });
```

Comment: yes, Code would be helpful

Comment: @MichaelMeyer i added code